# Windows Server/.NET-based email dropbox implementation

Tags: .net, email

We're developing a SaaS application, which, among other things, has to have email integration: whenever a user sends an email to a unique email address (such as `dropbox+af74c123@example.com`), our .NET service has to handle this message - pretty common nowadays, I guess.

Before starting to design anything, I'd like to know what is the approach for dealing with this. We have, though, several requirements:

- Preferably, use only standard Windows Server 2008 (R2) components
- Each customer has to have a unique email address
- Provisioning of a new email address should be as painless as possible - preferably, email server should accept mail sent to *any* address and let the callback handle the rest
- Avoid polling as much as possible - the email server has to notify our service of new messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's not a Server 2008 component, but you could avoiding polling if you use a custom server like this [managed email server](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/eng/products/mail_server/mail_index_eng.aspx?type=info). Account management and handling are pretty straightforward. Free for commercial use and relaxed license. We have been using it for a year in production.

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find any info on "catch-all" address and how callbacks are implemented. Can you give any hints here, please?

Comment: See IMailServerAPI, you can add a Filter which accepts an assembly and class name as parameters. You can implement your custom logic from there. The ISmtpMessageFilter you implement has access to sender, recipient, server api, etc.